# I have a problem positioning an element with css

Tags: html, css

I want to  place "Shop by category" beside the ebay logo using margin-left and margin-top.

margin-left is not working  or pushes some elements with it [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU1rN.png)

```css
.navclass >ul >li{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
padding:5px 25px;
//float:left;
margin-top:1px;
margin-left:20px;
border:1px solid black;}
```

in the html i made the image and search in a separate div
and added this down

```html
</div>
<nav class="navclass">
   <ul> 
    <li>Shop by <br> Category
     <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li>Collectibles&art</li>
     <li>Electronics</li>
     <li>Collectibles&art</li>
     <li>Collectibles&art</li>
     <li>Collectibles&art</li>
 </ul>
<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
   </li>
   </ul>

  </nav>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "php"? You also didn't post any code.

Comment: The HTML doesn't include the Ebay logo, so how can we place your "Shop by category" next to it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use **float:left;** in css for logo and nav? You will get what you want and i think that will work better. Because margins can not work with different size screens i think.